# How do i compare a date and a text coming from a text file with a date and text in SQL server and do the further transformation as needed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I need to develop a SSIS package and the need is to check two things before the data gets inserted.

There would be a text file where there would be a date and a text (anydate,text) and there is a table in sql server which will have the same pair of data(only one row where i might update it every time and i will insert data there for the first load so that it can be compared from the date and text coming from text file).

My question is, how can i compare the data coming from the text and the data coming from the sql server and do my transformation on the basis of true or false(if date matches do something and if it doesn't match update the present date in sql with this new date and do something else)

Comment: Can you put some code as example to show us what you've tried first?

Comment: Use a lookup transformation? Not really clear what you're *really* asking here.

Comment: i want to compare a date which is previously present in a sql server table to the date which i will be pulling from a text file

Comment: @Larnu i think he is looking to perform an upsert operation

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how can i compare the data coming from the text and the data coming from the sql server and do my transformation on the basis of true or false(if date matches do something and if it doesn't match update the present date in sql with this new date and do something else)

You are looking to perform an **Upsert** operation. To do that you need first a lookup transformation to check if the row exists; if lookup matched (row exists) use an OLEDB command to update the row else use an OLE DB destination to achieve that. You can refer to the following link for a step-by-step guide:

- [SSIS: Perform upsert (Update/Insert) using SSIS Package](http://azkhairuzzaman.blogspot.com/2015/09/ssis-perform-upsert-updateinsert-using.html)

*Note that lookup transformation is case sensitive*

---

Another method is to use Merge Join and conditional split:

- [SSIS insert and update rows in a table based on the contents of a Excel file](https://itssmee.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/ssis-insert-and-update-rows-in-a-table-based-on-the-contents-of-a-excel-file/)